# CakePHP 3.x - File Upload Results in Token Mismatch

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.6

I have a form that is type => file, with an file upload control.

When I submit this form without a file, it submits as expected.

However, When I submit the form with a file attached, I get a CSRF Token Mismatch.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

---

### EDIT: I noticed that the csrf token is the same when i refresh the page, maybe this is part of the problem?

---

### EDIT-2: When I disable the CSRF protection, the $this->request->getData() array is empty

---

### EDIT-3: I have hooked XDebug up and these are the results...

### [image: Xdebug File Upload CSRF Token Mismatch]

### Apparently $post and $header are null/empty on line 194, resulting in token mismatch

### [image: Xdebug File Upload CSRF Token Mismatch 2]

### Here is my Form

```
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
        <?php if(isset($ledger->id)) { ?>
        <?= $this->Form->create($ledger, ['url' => '/shortcut/ledger_save/' . $ledger->id, 'type' => 'file', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?= $this->Form->create($ledger, ['url' => '/shortcut/ledger_new', 'type' => 'file', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']); ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $this->Form->setTemplates(['inputContainer' => '{{content}}', 'submitContainer' => '{{content}}']); ?>
        <!-- Default box -->
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <?php if(isset($ledger->id)) { ?>
                    <h3 class="box-title">Edit <?= $ledger->ledger_title ?> Form</h3>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <h3 class="box-title">Create Ledger Form</h3>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <center>
                            <?php if($ledger->disabled == 'n') { ?>
                                <?= $this->Form->control('disabled', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'minimal']) ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check to disable (hide) ledger.
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?= $this->Form->control('disabled', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'minimal', 'checked']) ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;Uncheck to enable (show) ledger.
                            <?php } ?>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ledger Title</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('ledger_title', ['label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ledger Title', 'autofocus']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Plates</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('total_plates', ['label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Total Plates (Total Images)']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Pages</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('total_pages', ['label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Total Pages (Total Physical Pages)']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Check Tribes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php $x = 0; ?>
                        <?php foreach($tribes as $tribe) { ?>
                            <?php if($x == 0) { echo '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-3">&nbsp;</div>'; } ?>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <?php if(in_array($tribe->id, $ledger_tribes)) { ?>
                                    <?= $this->Form->control('tribe_id[]', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'minimal', 'value' => $tribe->id, 'checked']) ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $tribe->name ?>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                    <?= $this->Form->control('tribe_id[]', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'minimal', 'value' => $tribe->id]) ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $tribe->name ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php $x = $x + 1; ?>
                            <?php if($x == 2) { echo '</div>'; $x = 0; } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if($x == 1) { echo '</div>'; $x = 0; } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Custodian</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('custodian', ['type' => 'textarea', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width: 100%', 'placeholder' => 'Custodian']) ?>
                            <?php if(!isset($ledger->overwrite_custodian) || $ledger->overwrite_custodian == 'n') { ?>
                                <?= $this->Form->control('overwrite_custodian_checkbox', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'minimal', 'value' => 'y']); ?> Overwrite Plate Custodian
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?= $this->Form->control('overwrite_custodian_checkbox', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'minimal', 'value' => 'y', 'checked']); ?> Overwrite Plate Custodian
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image Source</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('image_source', ['label' => false, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Image Source']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Provenance</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('provenance', ['type' => 'textarea', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width: 100%', 'placeholder' => 'Provenance']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Global Keywords</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?php $keywordOptions = []; ?>
                            <?php $keywordValues = []; ?>
                            <?php $foundKeywords = []; ?>
                            <?php foreach($keywords as $keyword) { ?>
                            <?php       if(trim($keyword->keyword) == '') { continue; } ?>
                            <?php       $keywordOptions[$keyword->keyword] = $keyword->keyword; ?>
                            <?php       if(in_array($keyword->keyword, $ledger_keywords)) { $keywordValues[$keyword->id] = $keyword->keyword; $foundKeywords[] = $keyword->keyword; } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?= $this->Form->select('keyword', $keywordOptions, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'value' => $keywordValues, 'multiple' => true]); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Additional Keywords</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?php $additionalKeywords = ''; ?>
                            <?php foreach($ledger_keywords as $keyword) { ?>
                            <?php       if(in_array($keyword, $foundKeywords) == false) { ?>
                            <?php           $additionalKeywords = $additionalKeywords . $keyword . ', '; ?>
                            <?php       } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php $additionalKeywords = substr($additionalKeywords, 0, strlen($additionalKeywords) - 2); ?>

                            <?= $this->Form->control('additional_keywords', ['type' => 'textarea', 'value' => $additionalKeywords, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width: 100%', 'placeholder' => 'Additional Keywords']) ?>

                            <p class="help-block">Seperated by commas.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Arist</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('artist', ['label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Artist']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Media</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('media', ['label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Media']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dimensions</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <?= $this->Form->control('dimensions', ['label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Dimensions']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if(!isset($ledger->id)) { ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Batch Upload</label>

                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <?= $this->Form->file('uploadfile', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'file')) ?>

                                <p class="help-block">Select the ledger images archive here.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-pill pull-right']) ?>
                </div>
            <!-- /.box-footer-->
            </div>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
```

### Here is the Form html output

```
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">

    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal" action="/shortcut/ledger_new"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/><input type="hidden" name="_csrfToken" autocomplete="off" value="06d11527d1e431fd1d1b73a6b96e9af1eec6a1fd6c2ede60cfdb06afdcff5b3c02216614f61ba68bf1bf0beeba8b5f7500319ec94ec278141ee4f480b4a4505f"/></div>   


                ..... SNIPPED TO MAKE MAX CHARS ALLOWED ....


                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-pill pull-right">Submit</button>                    </div>
            <!-- /.box-footer-->
            </div>
                    </form>        <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
</section>
```

---

### Here is the inspection headers

### [image: Chrome Inspection Headers]

### Here is the inspection headers without the file upload populated, as you can see, in the above picture there is no Form Data, and in the below picture there is.

[image: Chrome Inspection Headers 2]

Comment: debug new/patchEntity

Comment: Are you sending csrf token..?Send it with ajax request.

Comment: example: ```$products = $this->Products->newEntity();  debug($products); ```

Comment: The newEntity/patchEntity code never fires as the CSRF MiddleWare is where the CSRF Token Mismatch occurs.

Comment: @ndm any ideas? Is there any other information that would help debug this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post_max_size inside the /etc/php.ini file was set to 8M, it has to be set larger than the uploaded file size.

So, what I did was, I set

```
 post_max_size = 80M
```

and I set

```
 upload_max_filesize = 60M
```

and the form submitted as expected after that